# Wordpress plugin won't send email

Tags: forms, wordpress

I'm using Jazzy Forms for two forms on my website. Each form is send via email to an email address.

The plugin worked fine untill today. Whenever I try to submit a form, it gives me an error. No email is sent.

Any idea what could fix this?

PS: the pages can be found here: 
http://ais-steigerbouw.be/standaard-materiaallijst/
and http://ais-steigerbouw.be/uitgebreide-materiaallijst/

Comment: It just says error. I tried to use the same plugin on a different wordpress site, and it work just fine there.

Comment: have you turned on debug in the wp_config.php?

Comment: 'Use of undefined constant JZZF_VERSION'

Comment: i see you have already posted on their support forum, they may have an answer for you.  You should add that error message to your post there.

Comment: Though I'd have more luck here :) The strange thing is that it works on another website, and it used to work on this website. Other parts of the form work (price calculation), but it doesn't send the form via email. If anyone finds a solution on the support forum, I'll post it here.

Comment: What access do you have to the server? can you see the logfiles (php/sendmail/apache etc)

Comment: I can access them, but I can't open them (.gz files). I also logged a php error, you can see it in the support thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/email-used-to-work-but-doesnt-anymore?replies=2